# ViewPager2 setCurrentItem bug workaround?

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

This reported bug is causing me problems;
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183847283

When combined with FragmentStateAdapter, ViewPager2.setCurrentItem doesn't always work. The TabLayout correctly changes (if you have one), but the ViewPager2 itself doesn't show the correct page.

Has anyone found a workaround?

Comment: Second problem is the `public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab)` is running during setup by the system (and not a user) and initiation must be masked. @rainai's solution, disable the smooth scroll solve this articles main topic for the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem, if not the same. The solution was to change `fragments`/`tabs`/`pages` in a specific order.

1. The `FragmentStateAdapter` should be notified first of the change to the fragment.
2. The `TabLayout` should then call `selectTab` under a `post`
3. The `ViewPager` should then call `setCurrentItem` under a `post`, inside the TabLayouts `post` to `selectTab`.

This may be overkill but it worked for me.

Example

```
//or some other notify depending on your use case.
fragmentStateAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);

tabLayout.post(()->{
     tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(position));
     viewPager2.post(()->{
          viewPager2.setCurrentItem(position);
          //I noticed on older devices like API 19
          //the viewPager wouldn't complete transformations
          //so we call this.
          viewPager2.requestTransform();
     });
});
```

Comment: In my experience, the `tabLayout` does not manually need to be updated, as it's already mediated in ViewPager2 via the `TabLayoutMediator`. Also, I think you can do away with the "nested" post. For me this simple code fixed the bug fully: `viewPager2.post {          viewPager2.setCurrentItem(position)}`

Comment: The system I was working with could change tabs programmatically, for example tabs could be added, removed, and navigated to, without interacting with the tab layout itself. The `TabLayoutMediator` is only automatically called when the user actually uses the tab layout, with this solution you could programmatically change the tab and `tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(position));` will provoke the mediator.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for me.  The only work-around that worked for me is to delay the call to ViewPager2.setCurrentItem() for 1000ms.  1000ms is an arbitrary value and may not even work if the device is very slow.

Comment: What worked for me is to disable smooth scrolling `ViewPager2.setCurrentItem(position, false)`.

Refer to my comment in the issue tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183847283#comment8

Comment: This answer does not solve the problem, still right active tab, but the ViewPager is showing first tab content and the tab it self as well. However the disable smooth scroll solution `ViewPager2.setCurrentItem(position, false)` makes it work fine! Looks to be a typical bug case, and let hope the bug will be updated to vanish. It is the best answer, but it is @rainai's and not mine, publish it!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                if (tab.getPosition()==0||tab.getPosition()==1||tab.getPosition()==2||tab.getPosition()==3){
                    pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
```

Comment: Sadly, same issue. TabLayout correctly changes, but ViewPager2 doesn't.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).